# Print the text in a block that matches the pattern to pattern by using awk/sed

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Have text like  below, need print only the block that contains `ABC:CDA*` and `fgh:qwe`.

Tried below Awk but its print all data.

```
awk -n  -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' 'match($0,".*fgh:qwe[^\n]*") { print substr($0,1,RLENGTH) }'
```

Input:

```
ABC:CDA_sd
dfg:GFJ
dfg:jasdn
iop:yui
ghj:bhu
ghj:poi
fgh:qwe

axy:ABC_gf
dfg:GFJ
dfg:jasdn
iop:yui
ghj:bhu
ghj:poi
fgh:qwe

ABC:CDA_ghg
dfg:GFJ
dfg:jasdn
iop:yui
ghj:bhu
ghj:poi
fgh:qwe

ABC:CDA_jsagdh
dfg:GFJ
dfg:jasdn
iop:yui
ghj:bhu
ghj:poi
fgh:qwe
```

Output:

```
ABC:CDA_sd
dfg:GFJ
dfg:jasdn
iop:yui
ghj:bhu
ghj:poi
fgh:qwe

ABC:CDA_ghg
dfg:GFJ
dfg:jasdn
iop:yui
ghj:bhu
ghj:poi
fgh:qwe

ABC:CDA_jsagdh
dfg:GFJ
dfg:jasdn
iop:yui
ghj:bhu
ghj:poi
fgh:qwe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
awk -v RS= '/^ABC:CDA.*fgh:qwe$/{ print sep $0; sep=ORS }' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to have more control on the output format, I suggest Perl
in paragraph mode

```
perl -00nE 'say "$1" if /ABC:CDA(.*)fgh:qwe/s' example
```

`Perl -00ne` means: for each paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '/^(axy:ABC_|ABC:CDA_)[[:lower:]]{2,6}$/ {check = ($1 == "axy:ABC_gf")} !check' file
ABC:CDA_sd
dfg:GFJ
dfg:jasdn
iop:yui
ghj:bhu
ghj:poi
fgh:qwe

ABC:CDA_ghg
dfg:GFJ
dfg:jasdn
iop:yui
ghj:bhu
ghj:poi
fgh:qwe

ABC:CDA_jsagdh
dfg:GFJ
dfg:jasdn
iop:yui
ghj:bhu
ghj:poi
fgh:qwe
```

Or only that data:

```
awk '/^(axy:ABC_|ABC:CDA_)[[:lower:]]{2,6}$/ {check = ($1 == "axy:ABC_gf")} check' file
axy:ABC_gf
dfg:GFJ
dfg:jasdn
iop:yui
ghj:bhu
ghj:poi
fgh:qwe
```